# Full Example Of Implementing Notifications For Core Data NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data, notifications, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Could somebody point me in the correct direction for a full implementation example of `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` 
`NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` 
and 
`NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`

I have read the references to it here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html

but I don't see a full example code of exactly where I should implement it so that my Views update correctly when I save my context.

In a current project I am saving and deleting in my `NSManagedObjectContext` but my app is crashing for some save operations.  From what I can tell I need to update my views so they implement `NSManagedObjectContextSaveNotification` but I don't know where to add it into my code.

Is there an example project I could download somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried the "Related sample code" at the top of the link you reference?

Answer (score 4):

Magical Record would be a reference example: [on github](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObjectContext/NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalObserving.m). But, rather than look at it and try to make your code work, just use MR to manage your Core Date setup instead.

A better option than using `NSManagedObjectContextSaveNotification` is probably to use `NSFetchedResultsController`. You're unlikely to need all added/removed objects when it happens, really you just want a trigger to refresh the UI and the FRC will do that for you. It'll also deal with getting the data you need as you need it (paged - if you configure it to do so) and appropriately sorted.

Comment: Why would you consider using `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` to be a "significant configuration issue"? Observing it is completely reasonable.

Comment: @TomHarrington Fair point, my comment was a little carte blanche and alarmist. I've done some rewording. Thanks.

Comment: Your link to github is the handling of the core data sync with iCloud. The intended method is -[NSManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:] and passing the notification that is received from the callback.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this website](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/core-data) to be very informative. Concurrency in core data is not a light subject, but it solves difficult problems that multi-threading creates.